# How do I alternate displaying two graphs by clicking one of two buttons using jquery and ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two graphs I want to display to the user. I want the first graph to display with two buttons below it when the page loads. I want to substitute the first graph with the second graph after the user clicks the first button (without reloading the page). I then want the first graph to reappear if the user clicks the second button.

I have successfully been able to achieve what I'm trying to do with the use of a dropdown. I just can't figure out how to adjust my code to work with buttons instead of a dropdown. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

jQuery:

```
$('#atl_graph').on('change',function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "/atlanta",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: {
            'selected': document.getElementById('atl_graph').value

        },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            Plotly.newPlot('graph', data );
        }
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="graph-container">
    <div class="graph-options">
        <label> Choose the plot type....</label>
        <select class="graph-options" id="atl_graph">
                <option value="No Seasons">No Seasons</option>
                <option value="Seasons">Seasons</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="graph">
        <script>
            var graphs = {{graph | safe}};
            Plotly.plot('graph',graphs,{});
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.atl_graph').on('click',function(){

$('#selected').html(this.value);
$('.atl_graph').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');


    $.ajax({
        url: "/atlanta",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: { 'selected': this.value },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            Plotly.newPlot('graph', data );
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  }

#selected {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}
  
  .left {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin-right: 0;
  }
    
  .right {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph-container">
    <div class="graph-options">
        <label> Choose the plot type....</label>
        <span class="graph-options" id="atl_graph">
                <button class="atl_graph left" value="NoSeasons">No Seasons</button><button class="atl_graph right" value="Seasons">Seasons</button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="graph">
        <script>
            var graphs = {{graph | safe}};
            Plotly.plot('graph',graphs,{});
        </script>
       <p>You selected: <span id="selected"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of using the change event on the select element, use the click event on the button (having made the buttons have the same class, and using the class as the selector). Then pass the value of the clicked button (`this.value`) to your AJAX function.

There's an extra bracket `{` somewhere in the code but it doesn't appear to be affecting the functionality.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you so much! One small tweak I made to your code was to add the selected class (.selected) to the first button. That way the first button is shown to be selected and matches the graph being displayed on page load.

Comment: Nice tweak, great idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
<button type="button" onclick="reloadGraph('No Seasons');">No Seasons</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reloadGraph('Seasons');">Seasons</button>

function reloadGraph(type) {
  $.ajax({
        url: "/atlanta",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: {
            'selected': type

        },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            Plotly.newPlot('graph', data );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a select control with ID `atl_graph`. Let's imagine that you have two buttons, with IDs `szns` and `noszns`. Let's also give each button the same class, `btnSznChg`, so that both button clicks can be detected with a single click event.

Here's how it could work:

```
<button id="szns" class="btnSznChg">Seasons</button>
<button id="noszns" class="btnSznChg">No Seasons</button>

$('.btnSznChg').click(function(){
    var tmp = this.id;
    var getgraph = (tmp == 'szns') ? 'Seasons' : 'No Seasons';

    $.ajax({
        url: "/atlanta",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: {
            'selected': getgraph /* getgraph value is either "Seasons" or "No Seasons" */

        },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            Plotly.newPlot('graph', data );
        }
    });

});
```

```js
$('.btnSznChg').click(function(){
    var tmp = this.id;
    var getgraph = (tmp == 'szns') ? 'Seasons' : 'No Seasons';
    console.log('Data sent via ajax is: ' + getgraph);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="szns" class="btnSznChg">Seasons</button>
<button id="noszns" class="btnSznChg">No Seasons</button>
```

Comment: This would work fine with two graphs, but not if there are more than two. Why not just assign the graph name to the button value, and use that?

Comment: Well, first Dustin said he had two graphs, so I went with that, and secondly I wanted to demo the ternary operator in case it was new to him. A useful little operator, that.